# Video.js caching my video?

Tags: javascript, caching, html5-video, video.js

i'm using videojs to play some video that resides on my server.

```
<video id="example_video_1" class="video-js vjs-default-skin"
          controls preload="auto" width="480" height="300" data-setup="{}" >
         <source src="http://www.site.eu/testvideo/<?php echo $linkVideo ?>.mp4" type='video/mp4' />
         <source src="http://www.site.eu/testvideo/<?php echo $linkVideo ?>.webm" type='video/webm' />
         <source src="http://www.site.eu/testvideo/<?php echo $linkVideo ?>.ogv" type='video/ogg' />
        </video>
```

I'm using CDN and i load dynamically the url of my videos,but changing the url not change the video that the player plays... It seems that CDN player holds a cache. I have have already tried to clear the browser cache and i have also change and reload the filename. How i can do to update the content of my player?

Comment: try to change video.src instead of source tags or remove and add again all sources

Answer (score 0):

Try setting src via Javascript and invoke play same way.

```
var video = _V_("example_video_1");
video.src(
    { type: "video/mp4", src: "<?php echo $linkVideo ?>.mp4" },
    { type: "video/webm", src: "<?php echo $linkVideo ?>.webm" },
    { type: "video/ogg", src: "<?php echo $linkVideo ?>.ogv" }
);
video.play();
```

You should call this code every time you update the source of the video.

Comment: What is `_V_`? What it's referring to?